# Filter in ERD-Diagram

Tags: entity-relationship

could someone help me with this problem.
I have some "filter-options", its RANGE and CODE.

With these filters i have to inner-join the BOOST-Entity on RANGE and CODE to get RESULT1.
Now i have to use RESULT1 and do a second inner join with DATA on the ID to get RESULT2.

I dont know how to draw it right, or can i complete this task with some other notation, like chen?

Here is a picture.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeWVx.jpg